# GKE cluster has unschedulable pods datadog-agent-v52f4

Tags: java, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We have an java app that's running in GKE, and it was using v1.23 which is about to EOL so we're trying to upgrade to a newer version. We upgraded to v1.24 and everything was good. So I choose to let google upgrade to v1.25 and now we have a problem.

the pool is configured with version 1.24.12-gke 1000 and an image type of Ubuntu with containerd

The nodes in the cluster view all show green ready.

But we're getting an error message:

**Problem**

Your cluster has 1 unschedulable pod

**Details** Unschedulable pods

datadog-agent-v52f4

I recognize that this is an old version of the datadog java agent, and I am guessing that I need to upgrade this as well.  But this is just my WAG about the problem and I haven't been able to find any information about what versions of the datadog agent work with which versions of GKE.

Also there's conflicting information displayed with regard to the cluster vs the Node pool. The cluster seems to be at 1.25.8-gke.500   but the pool is still at 1.24.12-gke.1000

Any suggestions about how to resolve my problem?

Comment: GKE won't upgrade the control plane and the node pools within the same 24 hour period.  So the node pool should be upgraded to 1.25 soon (or you can manually update as well).

As for the DD agent, do you have any more details on why the pod can't be scheduled?  Maybe the event log for the pod has some details?  `kubectl describe pod ...`

Answer (score 2):

The cluster seems to be at 1.25.8-gke.500 but the pool is still at 1.24.12-gke.1000 > This is expected behavior, the master upgrade always occurs first, followed by the worker nodes.